# Using xlsxwriter merge_row errors

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am exporting an excel file with xlsxwriter and I am trying to merge multiple cells using `.merge_range()` but I appear to be receiving errors related to constant memory even though I have set this to False.

workbook is initiate with below:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'\\network\Checking doc\Monthly Checks.xlsx', {'constant_memory' : False})
```

Cell formatting is handled by:

```
merge_header = workbook.add_format({'align' : 'center', 'valign' : 'vcenter', 'border' : 1})
merge_header.set_bg_color('#BFBFBF')
```

The merging of cells uses a for loop in a for loop which looks through 2 lists to get the cell coordinates.

My lists don't have good names I know but they are:

```
other_checkheads = ["C6 - LOGS", "C7 - HWS", "C8 - TMP", "C9 - WUP", 

"C10 - SWUP", "C11 - ADGP", "C12 - FWSWFIRM", "C13 - WBFIL", "C14 - FILES", "C15 - DOMPASS", "C16 - NAT",
"C17 - SECGP", "C18 - BIOS", "C19 - BIOSFW", "C20 - MOT", "C21 - SSL", "C22 - WARR"]
checkheads_letters = ["Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG"]
```

The loop is:

```
for letter in checkheads_letters:
                for head in other_checkheads:
                    row = ((letter + str(2)) + (":") + (letter +str(4)))
                    worksheet.merge_range(row, head, merge_header)
                    print (row)
```

When I run this and try open the document I receive the error:
"We found a problem with some content in 'Monthly Checks.xlsx'. Do you want us to try recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

I click yes and then get a file in use error stating the document is locked for editing by 'another user'. If I select to notify the person it then opens the document successfully with a note on the repairs which were made.

If I completely remove the fr loops the document opens without any errors.

Comment: XlsxWriter merges ranges don’t work in constant_memory mode if they extend past the current row. It is a documented limitation of constant_memory mode.

Comment: @jmcnamara yeah I've set constant memory to False to get around that. But it still has issues because of those specific merged cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error because the first row of the for loop applies 17 times the merge_range function into the same cell range (because your list has that many elements).

This is giving error:

```
for letter in checkheads_letters:
    for head in other_checkheads:
        row = ((letter + str(2)) + (":") + (letter +str(4)))
        worksheet.merge_range(row, head, None)
```

[image]

This one will work:

```
for letter in checkheads_letters:
    head = other_checkheads[checkheads_letters.index(letter)]
    row = ((letter + str(2)) + (":") + (letter +str(4)))
    worksheet.merge_range(row, head, None)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a loop in other parts of my code which has a loop inside it but the 2nd uses a range not another list and they work as intended. So not sure why one works but not the other.

Happy it works now, thank you.